# salivate at/over

Tags: prepositions

Please help me to choose the correct one (If you would, Please also explain your answer a bit).

1. I salivated **at/over** seeing it.
2. I salivated **at/over** the thought of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: #1 isn't a particularly likely thing to say. As with [Pavlov's well-known Dogs](http://www.simplypsychology.org/pavlov.html), such figurative use of *salivate* is normally in reference to *anticipation*, but that's not actually part of the verb itself. So you salivate *at the prospect of, at the thought of, in anticipation of [doing/seeing something]*. On average, **at** is very much more common than **over** where both are credible, but with the very common "adverbial" *in anticipation*, it can only be **in**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first one can easily be both **at/over**. **At** implies "at the moment of seeing it", whereas **over** implies "reflecting" on the memory of it. That leads us to the second sentence (where you have a mistake. It should be "the thought of it".) where **at** is the best option. "Over" could also be used in my opinion, but "at" implies "at the moment of thinking", in a similar way to my explanation of the first sentence. See: [over - 14](http://thefreedictionary.com/over) and [at - 9](http://thefreedictionary.com/at).

Comment: Thank you JMB. I really need to improve my prepositional skills :) while waiting for an answer I find out that we can use "on" too. but I think it's not common. I have added article "the" as you said. Thank you again, JMB.

Comment: Other prepositions could be used as well. In particular, _I salivated **upon** seeing it_ would also work, with 
_upon_ meaning "at the moment of" (see [upon - 4](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/upon)).

Comment: Absolutely. "I salivated **when** thinking about it". OP, as you say, read up on/think about the specificity of your prepositions, as this is really quite a "choice" scenario.

Comment: Thank you, J.R. for suggestion and also JMB . For conclusion, if i rewrite my first sentence based on what you have said, it should be something like this : "I salivated on the memory of seeing it." Is this right?

Comment: Unfortunately, "at/over" would be better here. "On/upon" are better suited before a verb in gerund in this case (see @J.R.'s example).